# Getting error 'link is invalid' once sharing a url with Google+

Tags: web, google-plus, web-deployment

I am trying to use G+ share link:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

But once a user click on the link it's giving error, "Link is invalid".

Kindly help!

Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the code, I am using: `<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.google.com" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
      <img src="/test-social-gp.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>`

Comment: There is a weird character in the .com `encodeURI('https://www.google.c‌​om')` => `https://www.google.c%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bom`